# With jQuery, how do I capitalize the first letter of a text field while the user is still editing that field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, capitalization

I'm looking for an example of how to capitalize the first letter of a string being entered into a text field.  Normally, this is done on the entire field with a function, regex, `OnBlur`, `OnChange`, etc. I want to capitalize the first letter while the user is *still* typing.

For instance, if I'm typing the word "cat", the user should press 'c', and then by the time he presses 'a', the C should be capitalized in the field.

I think what I'm going for might be possible with `keyup` or `keypress` but I'm not sure where to start.

Anyone have an example for me?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Just use CSS.

```
.myclass 
{
    text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

Comment: This will capitalize EVERY word.

Comment: @Kaleb The 'capitalize' value capitalizes the first character of each word. http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_text_text-transform.asp

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean, the OP only wants to capitalize the first word of the entire field.

Comment: @Anurag: OP = Original Poster.  In this case tresstylez.

Comment: @Kaleb:  Are you sure?  The only example given was for the word "cat"

Comment: Although this doesn't help the OP since it doesn't affect form fields the :first-letter pseudo-element will only affect the first letter of a block of text.

Comment: This was simple and worked great. I type the first letter and there was no delay in the capitalization in FF and only a miniscule delay in IE, as if I had CAPS LOCK on for the first letter.  Thanks Chris.

Comment: In Google Chrome - this will still allow ALL CAPITALS to be entered. JS is required to get it to also convert that to Sentence Case.

Comment: @Aaron: correct.  Actually, none of the browsers translate entered all caps back into initial caps only.  Weird, but good find.

Comment: This capitalization only changes the visualisation, backend will receive the input as it was typed. This may lead to unexpected appearances of same text with lowercase.

Comment: using jQuery you can always: `$("foo").css('text-transform','capitalize')`

Comment: i thing that is wrong, this only show as capitalize, but when send a form in the inspector send uncapitalize...

Answer (score 93):

This will simply transform you first letter of text:

`yourtext.substr(0,1).toUpperCase()+yourtext.substr(1);`

Comment: Simple and sweet. Helped me in my case :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since this actually modifies the user input were you to use it as input for backend.

Comment: The accepted answer need to create <tag> and add .class; this one is no need!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer; the currently accepted answer is a workaround only.

Answer (score 32):

I answered this somewhere else . However, here are two function you might want to call on 
keyup event.

To capitalize first word

```
  function ucfirst(str,force){
          str=force ? str.toLowerCase() : str;
          return str.replace(/(\b)([a-zA-Z])/,
                   function(firstLetter){
                      return   firstLetter.toUpperCase();
                   });
     }
```

And to  capitalize all words

```
function ucwords(str,force){
  str=force ? str.toLowerCase() : str;  
  return str.replace(/(\b)([a-zA-Z])/g,
           function(firstLetter){
              return   firstLetter.toUpperCase();
           });
}
```

As @Darrell Suggested

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(evt){

      // force: true to lower case all letter except first
      var cp_value= ucfirst($(this).val(),true) ;

      // to capitalize all words  
      //var cp_value= ucwords($(this).val(),true) ;


      $(this).val(cp_value );

   });
```

Hope this is helpful

Cheers :)

Comment: This capitalises the next letter on from foreign characters such as Polish ł ę ą etc. "małopolska" = "MałOpolska"

Comment: You should not use a regex on ascii characters but just always toUpperCase the first letter.

Comment: Best practice would be better to use `.blur()` as otherwise users cannot use `Ctrl`+`A` to select all.

Answer (score 28):

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(evt){
    var txt = $(this).val();


    // Regex taken from php.js (http://phpjs.org/functions/ucwords:569)
    $(this).val(txt.replace(/^(.)|\s(.)/g, function($1){ return $1.toUpperCase( ); }));
});
```

Comment: FYI this script will stop your users using cursor keys in the textbox.

Answer (score 27):

CSS solution with "text-transform: capitalize;" is no good if you want to use the contents of the input in backend. You will still receive data as-is. JavaScript solves this issue.

JQuery plugin combined from some of the techniques mentioned earlier, plus it capitalizes words after hyphens, i.e.: "Tro Lo-Lo":

Add to your script:

```
jQuery.fn.capitalize = function() {
    $(this[0]).keyup(function(event) {
        var box = event.target;
        var txt = $(this).val();
        var stringStart = box.selectionStart;
        var stringEnd = box.selectionEnd;
        $(this).val(txt.replace(/^(.)|(\s|\-)(.)/g, function($word) {
            return $word.toUpperCase();
        }));
        box.setSelectionRange(stringStart , stringEnd);
    });

   return this;
}
```

Then just attach capitalize() to any selector:

```
$('#myform input').capitalize();
```

Comment: I think this should be the answer for this question as the css solution is only a representation.

Answer (score 19):

I used the code of @Spajus and wrote a more extended jQuery plugin.

I wrote these four jQuery functions:

- `upperFirstAll()` to capitalize ALL words in an inputfield
- `upperFirst()` to capitalize only the FIRST word
- `upperCase()` to convert the hole text to upper case
- `lowerCase()` to convert the hole text to lower case

You can use and chain them like any other jQuery function:
`$('#firstname').upperFirstAll()`

My complete jQuery plugin:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({

    // With every keystroke capitalize first letter of ALL words in the text
    upperFirstAll: function() {
        $(this).keyup(function(event) {
            var box = event.target;
            var txt = $(this).val();
            var start = box.selectionStart;
            var end = box.selectionEnd;

            $(this).val(txt.toLowerCase().replace(/^(.)|(\s|\-)(.)/g,
            function(c) {
                return c.toUpperCase();
            }));
            box.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        });
        return this;
    },

    // With every keystroke capitalize first letter of the FIRST word in the text
    upperFirst: function() {
        $(this).keyup(function(event) {
            var box = event.target;
            var txt = $(this).val();
            var start = box.selectionStart;
            var end = box.selectionEnd;

            $(this).val(txt.toLowerCase().replace(/^(.)/g,
            function(c) {
                return c.toUpperCase();
            }));
            box.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        });
        return this;
    },

    // Converts with every keystroke the hole text to lowercase
    lowerCase: function() {
        $(this).keyup(function(event) {
            var box = event.target;
            var txt = $(this).val();
            var start = box.selectionStart;
            var end = box.selectionEnd;

            $(this).val(txt.toLowerCase());
            box.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        });
        return this;
    },

    // Converts with every keystroke the hole text to uppercase
    upperCase: function() {
        $(this).keyup(function(event) {
            var box = event.target;
            var txt = $(this).val();
            var start = box.selectionStart;
            var end = box.selectionEnd;

            $(this).val(txt.toUpperCase());
            box.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        });
        return this;
    }

    });
}(jQuery));
```

Groetjes :)

Answer (score 13):

My personal favorite when using jQuery is short and sweet:

```
function capitalize(word) {
   return $.camelCase("-" + word);
}
```

There's a jQuery plugin that does this too. I'll call it... jCap.js

```
$.fn.extend($, { 
    capitalize: function() {
        return $.camelCase("-"+arguments[0]); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: This looks good to me.. much better than other answers.. because it enables me to think in terms of existing functionalities provided by a well-known library called jQuery. Thanks for the impetus.

Comment: Why would you prefer my method over simply using css? Just curious. what's the use-case?

Comment: I'd prefer this approach over CSS, because it actually capitalizes the strings (i.e it is done at the data level), instead of just rendering capitalized text (i.e it is done at the presentation level). At the data level, we can do much more than just mere capitalization, so it makes sense to do that (and all such stuffs) at data level itself (in general).

Comment: But this doesn't handle multiple words. See my version below which is a modification of @Todd 's but supports and number of words in string.

Answer (score 10):

```
 $("#test").keyup(
     function () {
         this.value = this.value.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + this.value.substr(1).toLowerCase();
     }
 );
```

Comment: Most elegant soution, and the useful one when you need to capitalize string values so CSS is not aplicable

Answer (score 7):

Slight update to the code above to force the string to lower before Capitaliing the first letter.

(Both use Jquery syntax)

```
    function CapitaliseFirstLetter(elemId) {
        var txt = $("#" + elemId).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#" + elemId).val(txt.replace(/^(.)|\s(.)/g, function($1) {
        return $1.toUpperCase(); }));
        }
```

In addition a function to Capitalise the WHOLE string:

```
    function CapitaliseAllText(elemId) {
         var txt = $("#" + elemId).val();
         $("#" + elemId).val(txt.toUpperCase());
         }
```

Syntax to use on a textbox's click event:

```
    onClick="CapitaliseFirstLetter('myTextboxId'); return false"
```

Answer (score 7):

this will help you in - convert first letter of each word to uppercase

```
<script>
  /* convert First Letter UpperCase */
  $('#txtField').on('keyup', function (e) {
    var txt = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(txt.replace(/^(.)|\s(.)/g, function ($1) {
      return $1.toUpperCase( );
    }));
  });
</script>
```

Example : this is a title case sentence -> This Is A Title Case Sentence

Answer (score 4):

My appologies. The syntax was off due to me being in a hurry and sloppy.  Here you go...

```
     $('#tester').live("keyup", function (evt)
        {
            var txt = $(this).val();
            txt = txt.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + txt.substring(1);
            $(this).val(txt);
        });
```

Simple but works. You would def want to make this more general and plug and playable. This is just to offer another idea, with less code. My philosophy with coding, is making it as general as possible, and with as less code as possible.

Hope this helps. Happy coding! :)

Comment: live is now depreciated. [`"As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()"`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 4):

It's very cool you can capitalize Only the first letter of an input field With this one.. If any one know how to capitalize Like CSS text-transform:capitalize, Please Reply ..
Here You go..

`$('input-field').keyup(function(event) {
        $(this).val(($(this).val().substr(0,1).toUpperCase())+($(this).val().substr(1)));
    });`

Answer (score 4):

If using Bootstrap, add:

```
class="text-capitalize"
```

For example:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control text-capitalize" placeholder="Full Name" value="">
```

Answer (score 2):

A turkish one. If someone is still interested.

```
 $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^([a-zA-Z\s\ö\ç\ş\ı\i\ğ\ü\Ö\Ç\Ş\İ\Ğ\Ü])|\s+([a-zA-Z\s\ö\ç\ş\ı\i\ğ\ü\Ö\Ç\Ş\İ\Ğ\Ü])/g, function ($1) {
        if ($1 == "i")
            return "İ";
        else if ($1 == " i")
            return " İ";
        return $1.toUpperCase();
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

With **Javascript** you can use:

```
yourtext.substr(0,1).toUpperCase()+yourtext.substr(1);
```

If by chance you're generating your web page with **PHP** you can also use:

```
<?=ucfirst($your_text)?>
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that accept exceptions(passed by parameters):

Copy the below code and use it like this: $('myselector').maskOwnName(['of', 'on', 'a', 'as', 'at', 'for', 'in', 'to']);

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.maskOwnName = function(not_capitalize) {
            not_capitalize = !(not_capitalize instanceof Array)? []: not_capitalize;

        $(this).keypress(function(e){
            if(e.altKey || e.ctrlKey)
                return;

            var new_char = String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase();

            if(/[a-zà-ú\.\, ]/.test(new_char) || e.keyCode == 8){
                var start = this.selectionStart,
                    end = this.selectionEnd;

                if(e.keyCode == 8){
                    if(start == end)
                        start--;

                    new_char = '';
                }

                var new_value = [this.value.slice(0, start), new_char, this.value.slice(end)].join('');
                var maxlength = this.getAttribute('maxlength');
                var words = new_value.split(' ');
                start += new_char.length;
                end = start;

                if(maxlength === null || new_value.length <= maxlength)
                    e.preventDefault();
                else
                    return;

                for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
                    words[i] = words[i].toLowerCase();

                    if(not_capitalize.indexOf(words[i]) == -1)
                        words[i] = words[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + words[i].substring(1,words[i].length).toLowerCase();
                }

                this.value = words.join(' ');
                this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
            }
        });
    }

    $.fn.maskLowerName = function(pos) {
        $(this).css('text-transform', 'lowercase').bind('blur change', function(){
            this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();
        });
    }

    $.fn.maskUpperName = function(pos) {
        $(this).css('text-transform', 'uppercase').bind('blur change', function(){
            this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Jquery or Javascipt doesn't provide a built-in method to achieve this.

CSS test transform (`text-transform:capitalize;`) doesn't really capitalize the string's data but shows a capitalized rendering on the screen.

If you are looking for a more **legit way** of achieving this in the data level using plain **vanillaJS**, use this solution =>

```
var capitalizeString = function (word) {    
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    if (word.indexOf(" ") != -1) { // passed param contains 1 + words
        word = word.replace(/\s/g, "--");
        var result = $.camelCase("-" + word);
        return result.replace(/-/g, " ");
    } else {
    return $.camelCase("-" + word);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use both CSS and jQuery solutions when achieving this. This will change both how it appears in the browser and the data value. A simple solution, that just works.

**CSS**

```
#field {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#field').keyup(function() {
    var caps = jQuery('#field').val(); 
    caps = caps.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + caps.slice(1);
    jQuery('#field').val(caps);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    .first-character{
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#F00;
        text-transform:capitalize;
   }
.capital-text{
    text-transform:uppercase;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempt.

Only acts if all text is lowercase or all uppercase, uses Locale case conversion. Attempts to respect intentional case difference or a ' or " in names.
Happens on Blur as to not cause annoyances on phones.
Although left in selection start/end so if changed to keyup maybe useful still.
Should work on phones but have not tried.

```
$.fn.capitalize = function() {
    $(this).blur(function(event) {
        var box = event.target;
        var txt = $(this).val();
        var lc = txt.toLocaleLowerCase();
        var startingWithLowerCaseLetterRegex = new RegExp("\b([a-z])", "g");
        if (!/([-'"])/.test(txt) && txt === lc || txt === txt.toLocaleUpperCase()) {
            var stringStart = box.selectionStart;
            var stringEnd = box.selectionEnd;
            $(this).val(lc.replace(startingWithLowerCaseLetterRegex, function(c) { return c.toLocaleUpperCase() }).trim());
            box.setSelectionRange(stringStart, stringEnd);
        }
    });
   return this;
}

// Usage:
$('input[type=text].capitalize').capitalize();
```

Answer (score -3):

Slight update to cumul's solution.

The function upperFirstAll doesn't work properly if there is more than one space between words. Replace the regular expression for this one to solve it:

```
$(this).val(txt.toLowerCase().replace(/^(.)|(\s|\-)+(.)/g,
```