# Wordpress capital comments

Tags: wordpress

I have people leaving comments on my Wordpress blog.

Sometimes they are not capitalizing the first letter of their sentences.

Is it possible to capitalize the comments of users before they are added to the database?

Any ideas?

UPDATE AND ANSWER:

I can't add the answer below yet, but the answer to hook into the comments is in the example on: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API - find your hook, and write some code in a plugin or in your theme.  If you don't care about the capitalization in the database, it might be easier to inject a bit of css that just capitalized the comments for you, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129696/capitalize-first-letter-of-sentences-css

Comment: For seo I guess it would be better to capitalize the real data...and i think I can build the code to do the caps, but how do I get between the comment SEND and the database?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#Database_Writes_2  Hook onto the comment_save_pre filter.