# How to apply Title Case in input box through css

Tags: javascript, css, textbox

I am using text-transform property to convert inputbox text into Title Case, But I am not getting the exact property or combination to do this.

I also tried

```
text-transform: capitalize;
text-transform: lowercase;
```

I am trying to auto conversion for these

```
nIklesh raut : Niklesh Raut

NIKLESH RAUT : Niklesh Raut
```

Or should I go with Javascript.

Comment: To use this its best to make sure your text is not uppercase already. Try adding !important

Comment: check these answers [Click Me](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3471157/4323504)

Comment: I cant use above css to make title case, I dont want to give indication to user to not put upper case text.

Comment: Given CSS will work for first letter of sentence not for each word.
.link { text-transform: lowercase; }
.link:first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129696/capitalize-first-letter-of-sentences-css

Comment: @Py. It was good discussion there but it was years ago. Still css have this limitation ?  I think new version of css might be fix this problem ?

Comment: I don't think so :/. `text-transform` is mostly unchanged in that regard (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform part specifications). And since then no pseudo-classes (a list here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes ) nor pseudo-elements (a list here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements ) matching this kind of behavior have been added.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do like following way using css. This will work for all word.

```css
input { 
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
    text-transform: none;
}
:-moz-placeholder { 
    text-transform: none;
}
::-moz-placeholder { 
    text-transform: none;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { 
    text-transform: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="test" />
```

**Note:** But this will work when user will type in small letter only. But, it will be useful to you to go further. To make it for all i think you should use Scripting.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pj1duof5/)**

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem once. `text-transform: capitalise` will only capitalise the first letter of the word. Other letters will not be affected.

For example:

```
<p>nIklesh raut</p>
<p>NIKLESH RAUT</p>
<p>niklesh RAUT</p>

p {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

outputs as:

NIklesh Raut

NIKLESH RAUT

Niklesh RAUT

http://codepen.io/jaycrisp/pen/YwjyME

I tried many things, and found no way to do this in CSS alone. Best option is to have server return a lowercase string, then the text transform will behave consistently. Note however, this is also problematic for names. E.g. Leo McGarry will be formatted to Leo Mcgarry.

If you don't have back end access, you'll need to convert to a lowercase string first in javascript.

### edit

The spec actually says the following:

> **capitalize**
>
> Puts the first character of each word in uppercase; other characters are unaffected.

https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/text-transform

Answer (score 2):

If you go with javascript, this would solve your problem

```
var str = "nIklesh raut";
str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
```

Ref: [How to capitalize first letter of each word, like a 2-word city?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878756/javascript-how-to-capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-like-a-2-word-city)

Answer (score 2):

```
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
line-height: 60px;
font-size: 40px;
position: relative;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
```

Use something like this.

Answer (score 0):

CSS will only effect the style of the text in your text, it won't change the underlying value of the text box. This means that when you access the value via JavaScript, or if you POST it to your server, the value  will be how it was entered, not converted to uppercase. You will need to do that yourself either with JS, or your your server side language.

Comment: Thanks for your ans, I am already converting this in server end, I am just searching answer for client end.

Comment: Well then you just need to do it with JS .toUpperCase() method.

Answer (score 0):

Tips : Please check reset css style sheet for any override for **text-transform**

**text-transform property - Definition and Usage**

The text-transform property controls the capitalization of text.

***Default value:***    none

***Inherited:***    yes

***Version:***  CSS1

***JavaScript syntax:***    object.style.textTransform="uppercase"

*All browsers fully supports the property.*

**CSS Syntax**

```
text-transform: none|capitalize|uppercase|lowercase|initial|inherit;
// For DOM 
document.getElementById("myP").style.textTransform = "capitalize";
```

**Property Values**

*none - No capitalization. The text renders as it is. This is default*

*capitalize - Transforms the first character of each word to uppercase*

*uppercase - Transforms all characters to uppercase*

*lowercase - Transforms all characters to lowercase*

*initial - Sets this property to its default value.*

*inherit - Inherits this property from its parent element.*

**Test working file :**

https://jsfiddle.net/tfn2k46n/