# Format input text to uppercase

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm begginer and I would like to build an event that started on change of input. The text entered in the input would be automatically formatted as follows:

1. The first letter must always be uppercase;
2. All other letters must be lowercase.

```js
function formating() {
  var nameOfPerson = document.getElementById("nameOfPerson").textContent;
  var nameOfPerson = nameOfPerson[0].toUpperCase() + (nameOfPerson - nameOfPerson[0]);
  document.getElementById("nameOfPerson").textContent = nameOfPerson;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nameOfPerson" onchange="formatting()" placeholder="type your name">
```

Comment: `+(nameOfPerson - nameOfPerson[0])` should be `+(nameOfPerson.substr(1))`

Comment: There is a typo. Function name should be `formatting`. 2 `t`s not 1

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34871518/how-to-apply-title-case-in-input-box-through-css

Comment: Your question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878756/javascript-how-to-capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-like-a-2-word-city

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
function formatting() {
  var nameOfPerson = this.value;
  if (nameOfPerson.length > 0) {
    nameOfPerson = nameOfPerson[0].toUpperCase() + nameOfPerson.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    this.value = nameOfPerson;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nameOfPerson" onchange="formatting.call(this)" placeholder="type your name">
```

Comment: What have you changes and why? Please explain.

Comment: Let's say the value entered in the input is: "hello";
The formatting should change the input value to: "Hello". @Rajesh

Comment: @neologikadesenvolvimento I know what you are trying to achieve. My comment meant, SO is for everyone including beginners. So just putting code is not a good answer. You should explain **What and Why** you have changed so everyone gets it

Comment: Running the code found a error. Can you please check it? @jackarms

Comment: Okay, now I understand your comment. I'll edit my question and describe it better. Thank you :) @Rajesh

Comment: As in Rajesh's answer it's usually best to not embed event handlers in the HTML, if you must do it you can all a `.call(this)` to bind the input element to `this` when the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using CSS, then this is the tricks:

```html
 <input type="text" id="nameOfPerson" placeholder="type your name" style="text-transform: capitalize;">
```

CSS `text-trasform` property can change your input text as `capitalize`, `lowercase` and `uppercase`.

Comment: This doesn't to anything for characters typed as capitals, e.g. FoOObAR stays capitalised as typed.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve this is:

```
nameOfPerson.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + nameOfPerson.substring(1);
```

#### When to do it?

**Blur**

You can do it when input looses focus(`blur`) event. This will allow user to input in any format and when he is done, then you apply your formatting.

```js
function formatting() {
  var nameOfPerson = this.value
  this.value = nameOfPerson.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + nameOfPerson.substring(1).toLowerCase();
}

var input = document.getElementById("nameOfPerson");
input.addEventListener('blur', formatting)
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nameOfPerson" placeholder="type your name">
```

---

**Input**

Or you can enforce formatting using `input` event. This will take care of typing and pasting actions.

```js
function formatting() {
  var nameOfPerson = this.value
  this.value = nameOfPerson.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + nameOfPerson.substring(1).toLowerCase();
}

var input = document.getElementById("nameOfPerson");
input.addEventListener('input', formatting)
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nameOfPerson" placeholder="type your name">
```

---

**Pointers**

- Avoid binding handlers in HTML. Anyone can change DOM using dev tools and change behaviour of your page.
- `textContent` as name suggest is used for text bindings and will return static text. Inputs have value binding and you should use `.value`
- When you use `onclange="formatting()"`, handler will not have context pointing to element and you will have to fetch it again and again and DOM queries are expensive. Using `.addEventListener()` will bind context and is preferred as you can add more than 1 handler.
- In `(nameOfPerson - nameOfPerson[0])`, `-` operator will convert value to numeric value and would yield `NaN`. When dealing with strings, use string helper functions.

Comment: I agree it's best not to specify handlers in HTML, but only to increase modularity of your page. Anyone can also edit and rerun a page's Javascript.

Comment: OP asked that everything else be made lowercase. Perhaps add a .toLowerCase() after you substr so that your solution is complete

Comment: @haxxxton You are right. Missed it. Please check the update