# Css trying to make first character in input field uppercase

Tags: html, css, input

I am trying to make the first character in a input field uppercase.

So far I have tried:

```
input:first-letter {text-transform:capitalize !important}
input:first-letter {text-transform:uppercase !important}
```

I have also tried to make the input field styled `display:block;` and `display:inline-block;` but with no luck.

I am using the latest version of chrome. If I look in the inspector the

```
input:first-letter {text-transform:capitalize !important} is flagged to be active but it does not work.
```

I am open to any Jquery solutions as well

Thanks,

Comment: styling the field using CSS doesn't change what's actually submitted with the form.  So if a user types in "foo" and that's styled using `text-transform:capitalize` to make it look like "Foo", the form will still send "foo" to the server when the form is submitted.

Comment: If you're looking for just the first letter on the first word in a collection of words to be capitalized, it cannot be accomplished with just css.

Comment: @andi this is just pure visual

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capitalize first letter of sentences CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129696/capitalize-first-letter-of-sentences-css)

Comment: OK, just wanted to make sure you knew.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`:first-letter` wont work on input field. but it works without that.

> So change it as `input {text-transform:capitalize;}` it works fine.
>   see demo

it works fine without `!important`

```css
input {text-transform:capitalize;}
```

```html
<input/>
```

As you have mentioned in pure css way i have added the above method

**Limitation:** It will capitalize all words in the input box. In pure CSS it is not possible to capitalize only the first word as of now. you have to try the jquery way to do this as given below

**Using jquery:-**

using `keyup` event

```js
$('input').keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val().length>0){
      var character = $(this).val().charAt(0);
      if(character!=character.toUpperCase()){
          $(this).val($(this).val().charAt(0).toUpperCase()+$(this).val().substr(1));
       }
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input/>
```

**To work even on mouse events:-** (like cut paste in mouse)

Using propertychange event by `$('input').bind('input propertychange', function() {`

```js
$('input').bind('input propertychange', function() {
    if($(this).val().length>0){
      var character = $(this).val().charAt(0);
      if(character!=character.toUpperCase()){
          $(this).val($(this).val().charAt(0).toUpperCase()+$(this).val().substr(1));
       }
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input/>
```

Comment: that will capitalize all words not just the first letter

Comment: This capitalizes the first letter _of every word_.  Not sure if this is what OP wants.

Comment: GabyakaG.Petrioli & @andi thats true. but we dont have a solution in pure css. see the tag lists only css. thats why given that. now i have updated the scenario

Comment: This almost works. But if you type in a word and press (cmd + a) to copy the text the copy function wont work - atleast on mac

Comment: Nvm this works: ```if ($(this).val().length == 1) {
                    $(this).val($(this).val().charAt(0).toUpperCase() + $(this).val().substr(1));
                }```  I had to change your commented lines

Comment: @user2722667 i have updated the answer to handle other keys(cmd + a) as well as copy and paste with mouse events also

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `onKeypress` listener and capitalize the first character of the value. Keep in mind this function will run every time a key is pressed in that `input`

```js
$( "#keypress" ).keypress(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  val = val.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + val.substr(1);
  $(this).val(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="keypress">
```

Answer (score 0):

For text output, you can easily make only the first character uppercase by css.

```
.mytable td {
    text-transform:lowercase;
}
.mytable td:first-letter {
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```