# Capitalize first letter of an inline element's text

Tags: html, css

I [read elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11137019/2648) that the following should capitalize the first letter of the text of an inline element (e.g. a `<span>`).

However, if you run the code snippet you'll see that it doesn't work. If I replace the `<span>` with a `<div>` it works, but is there a way to capitalize the first letter without changing the element type?

```css
.list .capitalize:first-letter {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <span class="capitalize">capitalize me</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `::first-letter` *"The ::first-letter CSS pseudo-element applies styles to the first letter of the first line of a **block-level** element"* [Source](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) . The answer you referenced has a comment --> *"Keep in mind that `.qcont` has to be a block."*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pseudo element `::first-letter` only works if the parent element is a block element, so the span must be `inline-block`:

```css
.list .capitalize {
  display: inline-block;
}
.list .capitalize::first-letter {
  /* you could use capitalize as well, but since it's just one letter, just use uppercase on it */
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <span class="capitalize">capitalize me</span>
</div>
```

Comment: While this is the correct answer, please use the new format `::first-letter` with two `::`

Answer (score 2):

Span has not default display, so you have to set it to block or something else
And it's not correct to set `display` property of `first-letter`, you should do it for entire class

```css
.list .capitalize{
  display: block;
}
.list .capitalize::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <span class="capitalize">capitalize me</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to make the `span` itself `display: inline-block` - not the `::first-letter` pseudo element.

```
.list .capitalize {
  display: inline-block;
}
```