# CSS - first letter capitalize

Tags: css

It is possible to make ONLY the first character set to uppercase with css? (e.g: :first-char selector)

in short: if the **text start with a number, do not apply the conversion (capitalize)** afterwards

```
table.evenOdd tr td::first-letter{
        text-transform:capitalize;
    }
```

the table

```
<table class="evenOdd">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 50%">question 1</td>
        <td><b>100 mm</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>question 2</td>
        <td><b>Success</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>question 3</td>
        <td><b>42 kilometer</b></td>
    </tr>  
</table>
```

and the result is 
Question 1 | 100 **M**m   -- nok i want mm
Question 2 | **S**uccess  -- ok
Question 3 | 42 **K**ilometer -- nok i want kilometer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capitalize first letter of sentences CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129696/capitalize-first-letter-of-sentences-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::first-letter` only works on block-level elements.

From MDN's [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter):

> The ::first-letter CSS pseudo-element applies styles to the first letter of the first line of a block-level element, but only when not preceded by other content (such as images or inline tables).

Set your `span`s to `inline-block` for this to work:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
}

span::first-letter {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<span>success</span>
<span>Warning</span>
<span>10 cm</span>
<span>128 kilometer</span>
```

Comment: Yes I thought of that, almost perfect but my data is in a table in td elements, so the inline-block causes my table to fall apart ://

Comment: It sounds like we might need a slightly more complete example of your layout in the original question to be able to provide a suitable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
span::first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: I could not find better, but the `<span>` must also have `display: block` and not be preceded by other content (such as images or inline tables) : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this:

```css
.uppercase {
  display: inline-block; 
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

.uppercase:first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase
}
```

```html
<span class="uppercase">success</span> 
<span class="uppercase">Warning</span> 
<span>10 <span class="uppercase">cm</span></span> 
<span>128 <span class="uppercase">kilometer</span></span>
```

Comment: The idea is good, but I have a lot of data 5000+ so I don't want to modify the content at html level (then I could modify the text itself to display properly)  -- I want to save time! :>

Comment: With the much data case, i think that you should the pre-format data by JS before show them.