# Auto capitilize Html Text Box for Desktop Browsers [chrome, safari, firefox ...]

Tags: html, css

I search on the web, but all the solutions are mobile only. Is there any autocapitalize  attribute for desktop browser such as Chrome, Firefox or Safari not in mobile devices.

What I actually want to do is that I want the create an input text, and in the scenario when user type something, input must start with capitalized letter

Is there any way to do it

Comment: possible duplicate of [make the first character uppercase in css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577364/make-the-first-character-uppercase-in-css)

Comment: Should the text be displayed with a capital letter, or should it actually be changed so that when the form is submitted, the submitted input has a capital letter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
input {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

[**See this fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qr8Lu/)

To extend on the answer if you wish the first letter to be capitalized on submit, you need to either add some javascript, e.g.:

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(evt){

      // force: true to lower case all letter except first
      var cp_value= ucfirst($(this).val(),true) ;

      // to capitalize all words  
      //var cp_value= ucwords($(this).val(),true) ;


      $(this).val(cp_value );

   });
```

([From this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017456/with-jquery-how-do-i-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-a-text-field-while-the-user))

Or perform some post processing on the server side (such as by using e.g. [in php](http://php.net/ucfirst) `ucfirst($string);`

Comment: thank you for the solution, it works on every browser

Comment: @user1929072 does this answer your question? Be aware that, while this **displays** the text with a capital letter, the real text remains unchanged. So when the form is submitted, you will get the text without capital letters.

Comment: @Nic, I've extended the answer with some options

Comment: @Nic I am using this variable in database search and it is case insensitive, so it is the answer for me

Answer (score 0):

```
input{
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RtA4k/